# Iterate on symfony2 translation element childs

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, yaml

I am using symfony2 translation tool with yml files types.

I have something like that :

```
carousel:
    slide1:
        title: At nunc si ad aliquem bene
        text: Altera sententia est quae
    slide2:
        title: Vita est illis semper in fuga
        text: Haec igitur lex in amicitia
    slide3:
        title: Cum haec taliaque sollicitas
        text: Tandem id ut optimum factu
```

Is it possible to iterate on "carousel" childs in twig with symfony?

Something like :

```
{% for slide in carousel|trans %}
    {{ slide.title }}
    {{ slide.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible without creating an extension.

However, you can do something like:

```
{% for i in range(1,carousel|length) -%}
    {{ 'slide' ~ i ~ '.title'|trans }}
    {{ 'slide' ~ i ~ '.text'|trans }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: I added the `range()` function to your answer. it's easier maintainable than `1..3` as it will automatically work with a growing number of carousel elements :)

Comment: @nifr the problem is that you don't have a carousel variable, I choose to use 1..3 to showit can't be done dynamically

Comment: I understand what you mean. you can't obtain the number of translations present in the (YAML-)translation-array. i just assumed this `carousel` variable in twig would represent an `Array(Collection)` holding the images (along with default texts) ... because almost all carousel plugins like the famous [jCarousel](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/) are primariliy used for image sliding.

Comment: This answer has a incorrect loop range now, as `carousel|length` just means the length of the text (e.g. 8).